# Return Value from Hashtable get function is a Reference?

Tags: java, hashtable

```
Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, HashSet<String>>> test = 
        new Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, HashSet<String>>>();
test.put("1", new Hashtable<String, HashSet<String>>());
Hashtable<String, HashSet<String>> actual = test.get("1");
actual.put("3", new HashSet<String>());
//test.put("1", actual);
HashSet<String> expected = test.get("1").get("3");
if ( expected == null ) {
 System.out.println("DIE");      
}
```

Based on the code above, I thought DIE would be printed out. But apparently, actual is a reference to the object inside test still. I was under the impression that I had to "put" back actual into test (shown by the line that had been commented out). Is there authoritative documentation on whether actual is a reference or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are always passed as a reference in Java. From [chapter 4 of JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html):

> The reference types are class types, interface types, and array types. ... The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these objects.

Comment: -1000 - Objects are NOT passed by references in Java.  Object references are passed by value.  This is a very, very important distinction.

Comment: While I think you're trying to say the right thing, nothing is "passed by reference" in Java. References are passed by value.

Comment: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html and so on.  PLEASE DO NOT PERPETUATE THIS MYTH.

Comment: @Stephen C: I reworded it slightly, but I believe I'm right in saying that *objects* are passed by/as a reference. I never said that the *variable* itself is passed by reference; if I did, that would be wrong.

Comment: @casablanca, your link does not exists anymore. Your argument added more to my confusion. Does what you say mean, if I `object obj= hashtable.get(idx)` and do `obj.prop = 'meCool'`, the next time I do `object obj= hashtable.get(idx)` and read `obj.prop` I'll get `'meCool'`?